# Spring Security OAuth2 with Keycloak - Accessing User Information

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

I have a `Spring Security OAuth2` with `Keycloak` setup.

On `Client` application side the artifacts look like this:

application.yml

```
server.port: 8182

spring:
    security:
        oauth2:
            client:
                registration:
                    keycloak:
                        client-id: myclient-ac
                        client-secret: 81e3fd9f-52ce-4549-8ea9-ae53e754da89
                        authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
                        redirect-uri: http://localhost:8182/login/oauth2/code/myclient-ac
                        scope: openid
                provider:
                    keycloak:
                        issuer-uri: http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrealm
                        #authorization-uri: http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth
                        #token-uri: http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
                        #user-info-uri: http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
                        #jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
                        #user-name-attribute: preferred_username
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login().disable()
            .oauth2Client();
            
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

WebClientConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {
    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client = 
            new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        
        return WebClient.builder()
            .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
            .build();
    }    

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
            .authorizationCode()
            .refreshToken()
            .build();

        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = 
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
}
```

MyRestControllerClient.java

```
@RestController
public class MyRestControllerClient {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRestControllerClient.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;     
    
    @GetMapping("/helloworld")
    public String helloworld(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("keycloak") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
        String body = webClient
            .get()
            .uri("http://localhost:8181/helloworld")
            .attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();
        
        LOGGER.info(body);
        
        return body;
    } 
    
    @GetMapping("/oidc-principal")
    public OidcUser getOidcUserPrincipal(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser principal) {
        return principal;
    }    
}
```

Accessing http://localhost:8182/helloworld results in being redirected to login page at `Keycloak`. Providing `username` and `password`, I can successfully access my `/helloworld` endpoint.

I want to access also the user information, according to `4.1. Accessing User Information` at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect it can be done in the `REST` controller via

```
@GetMapping("/oidc-principal")
public OidcUser getOidcUserPrincipal(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser principal) {
    return principal;
}
```

Adding this endpoint to my `REST` controller, and accessing it after the `/helloworld` endpoint, results in `principal` being `null`.

How to access the user information?

Comment: What is your specific question? Since you've answered your own post and edited the OP, it's not clear to me.

Comment: I assume that my answer is the solution to my question. Still I don't understand the difference in .oauth2Login().disable() and .oauth2Login(), because the overall behavior is the same.

Comment: `.oauth2Login()` adds support for OpenID Connect 1.0 as an authentication mechanism. Without it, you're not actually authenticated in your application, which is why the `@AuthenticatedPrincipal` would not return the correct information about the currently logged in user. You can use `.oauth2Client()` independently, and use something else to log into your application, or you can use them together and simultaneously log into your application using keycloak (login) AND use the returned access token for making secure API calls to resource servers in your architecture (client).

Comment: [This section of the reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#oauth2login) will explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed this

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login().disable()
            .oauth2Client();
            
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

to

```
.oauth2Login()
.and()
.oauth2Client();
```

now `principal` is full of information.

But what's the difference now? `OAuth2` worked with `.oauth2Login().disable()` as expected, the behavior is the same, I get redirected to the login page at Keycloak, and the login happens with or without `.disable()`

Comment: Is it an answer or another question?